# Playing video by streaming from kaltura in Android

Tags: java, android, webview, kaltura

Please anybody help me to play video by streaming from kaltura in android.I already tried with Webview but failed to play and the link for video is :-

http://kaltura.sine-mania.com/index.php/kwidget/cache_st/1405072601/wid/_100/uiconf_id/6709464/entry_id/0_ts1loab6

is there any alternate way please guide me.

Comment: use vitamio lib for vedio streaming https://www.vitamio.org/en/Download/ also use a device to test your app not on emulator

Comment: did u figure it out ?

Answer (score 0):

You are using legacy embed code that only include flash embed, in order to play html5 content you need to change your embed method to auto or dynamic embed.
please look at player.kaltura.com site for more information about it.

thanks,